# Run PHP at specific time - oneliner

Tags: linux, command-line, at

I'm trying to run some code that sends an SMS at a specific time in the future. All on one line...

Here's my command line command:

```
php -r 'include_once("/home/eamorr/open/open.ie/www/newsite/ajax/constants.php");sendCentralSMS("0878482849","hi");' | at now + 3 minutes
```

But this sends the message immediately. It doesn't wait 3 minutes!

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your command is wrong because you're executing the first command and then you're sending the output to the at command.

I don't know why, but it seems that it works if you wrap your command with echo:

```
echo "your command" | at now + 3minutes
```